# Create a SEO friendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
index.php
-------------
<?php  
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234","mspl_test");
    $data = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM products");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="container">
            <table border="1">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <?php  
                    while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($data))
                    {

                        echo "<tr><td><a href='exp.php?id=$row[0]&name=$row[1]'>$row[0]</a>
                        <td><a href='exp.php?id=$row[0]&name=$row[1]'>$row[1]</a>";
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

exp.php
-------
<?php  
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    echo "<h1 align='center'>Hello! You've selected $name having id of $id</h1>";
?>

.htaccess
---------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^product?$ exp.php?id=$1&name=&1

</IfModule>
```

When user clicks on a link some id or name..it shows the url http://localhost/slug/exp.php?id=1&name=Google Nexus 4. i want to remove this id=1&name=Google Nexus 4 and make it seo friendly. i know i can sanitize my url with .htaccess.but it doesn't work. when i click it still shows the query string urls rather than just product.

Comment: Are you sure that .htaccess is working at your localhost

Comment: What king of URL SEO friendly do you want? `http://localhost/slug/1/Google Nexus 4/`?

Comment: @Vivek it's in the localhost/slug folder

Comment: @Vivek I don't see that claim?

Comment: @Shiva http://localhost/slug/google-nexus-4

Comment: @L.Moharana u'r using apache or nginx? ;)

Comment: @MarcelD I'm using Apache 2.xx